# Update data in Current view using a timer

Tags: ios, iphone

In my app, I am using two UIViews. One of these is for displaying different data. Data is displayed by pressing a button from other view. I want to update data that is currently displayed probably using a timer. Its working should be so that selected function like a table,graph or pi chart in that view is updated after a specific time. I am thinking of some lengthy and complex way. Is there some easy way for this?
As an example: multiple buttons are in first view. User clicks any of the one,related to that button functions are performed and related data is displayed in second view. So when the timer expires(reaches to zero),there should be a check,which button is currently pressed or which method is currently called to show data in second view. That method should be repeatedly called. Like input data changes,output should change in response.

Comment: I didn't understand what you are asking about !!

Comment: If you want to use a timer, use a `NSTimer`. You can set a `NSTimer` to repeatedly call a method at a set interval.

Comment: NSTimer use scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.... it's call method method repeatedly some interval.

Comment: Actually its not confirm which method is currently being used. If there is a way to detect which method is being used or which button is lastly clicked,then that method can be repeatedly called using NSTimer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure, if I understand what u are asking. But if u intent to do something after a specific time u can use this.

```
int delayTime = 8;

dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayTime * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        // DO SOMETHING HERE!!
    });
```

Comment: Code is fine. Just in "do something" how to check which input data is changed at run time and what is currently displayed. Like a table is displayed and its data is accessed online. As data is changed, it should update tableview,pie chart or anything. is it fine that I call "reload" for every display? will it update view automatically?